# boost test -- "The ordinal 313 could not be located"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-test

I'm trying to run an application that uses boost test via dynamic link. I have an application's exe file and boost_unit_test_framework-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll in the same directory. When I try to launch it gives me the following error:

[image]

Why? How can I fix it?

btw I'm using MSVC-12.0 and boost 1.55.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I just need to put SSL dynamic libraries in the same directory.